# Unidentified constant and assumed as

Tags: php, html, forms

Im having problem with this codes, im using the IDs for values in echo. for example.

```
echo "<label for='prod_brand'>Product Brand:</label><br />
      <input name='prod_brand' id='prod_brand' type='text' maxlength='150' class='col1' placeholder='Auto Complete Form' value='$prodbrand'/>
      <div class='clear'></div>";
```

I am getting errors when doing so, how do i fix it? i need to query the results inside the form so I can edit it.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $prodbrand    = $row[prod_brand];
     $prodname     = $row[prod_name];
     $prodcategory = $row[prod_category];
     $prodprice    = $row[prod_price];
     $proddesc     = $row[prod_desc];
     $prodpic      = $row[prod_pic];
     $prodquantity = $row[prod_quantity];
```

Comment: If you find you're doing this kind of assignments often, you can make your life easier by using [the `extract()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes around your array keys:

```
$prodbrand = $row['prod_brand'];
$prodname = $row['prod_name'];
$prodcategory = $row['prod_category'];
$prodprice = $row['prod_price'];
$proddesc = $row['prod_desc'];
$prodpic = $row['prod_pic'];
$prodquantity = $row['prod_quantity'];
```

Comment: OH.. Maybe im too tired. hahaha Thank you!! What a simple answer. haha

Answer (score 0):

Array access keys are strings:

```
$row["prod_brand"]
```

And not:

```
$row[prod_brand]
```

Comment: Thank you! im think im too tired to think properly. haha